# Changing stacked images opacity value on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 images with the same dimensions. The `<img>` uses a 100% width (they're all stacked one on top of the other), and below them I have standard content.

**The needed effect is:**

1. As soon as I begin scrolling down, the actual scroll of the page must be blocked while the 2nd image starts appearing (by smoothly changing its `opacity` value from 0 to 1).
2. Once it reaches 100% `opacity`, the 3rd image should start appearing, and so on.
3. When the 4th image reaches 100% `opacity`, the scroll behavior should normalize itself to allow the user to scroll down to the rest of the page.
4. If the user scrolls up, the same effect should be applied, just backwards.

Here's an initial [codepen link](https://codepen.io/asantos-the-sasster/pen/abGYJxK), don't really know how to implement the effect. Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried using GSAP with ScrollTrigger? It looks like your problem could be very easily solved using this library. Here is the link to the documentation: https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger
There is an option called `pin` that should do the trick. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/YzXdbQo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk why is everyone making it so complicated but here have a simple approach.

Use gsap library.

```js
const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: document.querySelector(".images"),
        pin: true,
        start: "top 0%",
        scrub: 1,
      },
    });

    duration = 3;

    tl.to(".img1", {
      duration: duration,
      opacity: 0,
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
    })
    
    .to(".img2", {
        duration: duration,
        opacity: 0,
    })
    
    .to(".img3", {
        duration: duration,
        opacity: 0,
    })
    
    .to(".img4", {
        duration: duration,
        opacity: 0,
    })
    
    .to(".content", {
        duration: duration,
        opacity: 1,
    },"-=1")
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.images {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.images img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  
  
  
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.images img.img1 {
  opacity: 1;
}



.content{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="images">
      <img
        src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/d99f2b/fff.png&text=4"
        alt="4"
        class="img4"
      />
      <img
        src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/44a10f/fff.png&text=3"
        alt="3"
        class="img3"
      />
      <img
        src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/3c00ff/fff.png&text=2"
        alt="2"
        class="img2"
      />
      <img
        src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/ff4400/fff.png&text=1"
        alt="1"
        id="img1"
        class="img1"
      />

      <div class="content">
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
        <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-IQLehpLoVS4fNzl7IfH8Iowfm5+RiMGtHykgZJl9AWMgqx0AmJ6cRWcB+GaGVtIsnC4voMfm8f2vwtY+6oPjpQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-wK2NuxEyN/6s53M8G7c6cRUXvkeV8Uh5duYS06pAdLq4ukc72errSIyyGQGYtzWEzvVGzGSWg8l79e0VkTJYPw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  ></script>
</html>
```

I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: This is definitely the most accurate answer!

Comment: Just curious, you did state "There should be no automatic opacity change into the next image at all. ", but this solution does have some of that.  Did you change your requirement?

Comment: @petern0691 hi, actually that comment was in the context of that other answer. The opacity was changing automatically when entering into the next block, instead of doing it gradually while the user scrolled (up / down).

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution based on feedback:

- Version 1 is as per initial understanding and has not been changed.
  It initiated an automatic smooth transition of the images using
  opacity whenever the user changed scrolling direction.
- Version 2 uses the scroll action itself to determine the opacity
  transition, and occurs at the rate scroll events are generated, again
  when the user changes scrolling direction.
- Version 3 refined as per further feedback in comments below.
- Version 4 refined as per further feedback in comments below. Opacity
  processing only occurs when scroll is at the "top", ie, "inside the
  images".

***Version 1***

I think the code below meets your requirements above.  Hopefully the embedded comments explain how it works.

This example uses 'setTimeout's to coordinate the fading of the images by queuing them.  It could also be done using 'setInterval' and iterating through the images instead of queuing them.

I have tweaked around a bit with the layout.  See the comments in the code.  Depending on your final layout, there are probably countless ways this could be done.

```js
var images;
var scrollContainer;
var noScrollDown;
var noScrollUp;
var scrollLeft;
var scrollTop;
var latch;
function setUp() {

    images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

    scrollContainer = document.getElementById("content");
    noScrollDown = true;
    noScrollUp = true;
    scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
    scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
    latch = false;
}

function doScrollUp () {
    noScrollUp = false;
    noScrollDown = true;
    scrollContainer.style.overflow = "auto";
    latch = false;
}

function doScrollDown () {
    noScrollDown = false;
    noScrollUp = true;
    scrollContainer.style.overflow = "auto";
    latch = false;
}

function fadeIn(ndx) {
    if ( ndx > 3 ) {
        //  Top image is showing so switch direction of allowable scrolling
        doScrollDown();
    } else {
        //  Fade in an image and queue the fade in of the next image
        images[ndx].style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 2000, ndx+1);        //  The time here, in milliseconds, should be the same as the transition time above
    }
}

function fadeOut(ndx) {
    if ( ndx < 1 ) {
        //  Bottom image is showing so switch direction of allowable scrolling
        doScrollUp();
    } else {
        //  Fade out an image and queue the fade out of the next image
        images[ndx].style.opacity = 0;
        setTimeout(fadeOut, 2000, ndx-1);       //  The time here, in milliseconds, should be the same as the transition time above
    }
}

function transOpacity() {
    if ( noScrollDown && scrollContainer.scrollTop >= scrollTop ) {
        //  No scroll down allowed, and scroll event tried to go down
        
        //  Scroll back to where the scroll was
        scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);  //  This will trigger another scroll event
        
        //  
        if ( ! latch ) {
            latch = true;       //  Stop double processing due to second scroll event triggered above
            scrollContainer.style.overflow = "hidden";
            fadeIn(1);
        }
    } else if ( noScrollUp && scrollContainer.scrollTop <= scrollTop ) {
        //  No scroll up allowed, and scroll event tried to go up
        
        //  Scroll back to where the scroll was
        scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);  //  This will trigger another scroll event
        if ( ! latch ) {
            latch = true;       //  Stop double processing due to second scroll event triggered above
            scrollContainer.style.overflow = "hidden";
            fadeOut(3)
        }
    } else {
        scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
        scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
        latch = false;
    }
}
```

```css
.images img {
    width: 100%;            /*  Note that 100% width will cover the scoll bar of the content, when the flow is decoupled with 'display: position;'  */
    max-height: 25vh;       /*  Set a limit on the height of the images, for this example, so that the scroll bar of the content can be fully accessible */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0vh;                 /*  Set the position, for this example, so that the scroll bar of the content can be fully accessible */
}


/*  Set up the required transition on the property relevant property  */

.images img.image {
    opacity: 0;                     /*  The default initial opacity  */
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 2s;        /*  The time here, in seconds, needs to be the same as the setTimeout times below  */
}


/*  Initialise the first image as showing, ie, full opacity.  */

.images img.image:nth-of-type(1) {
    opacity: 1;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 25vh;       /*  For this example, make sure the scroll container is below the images so that the scroll bar is fully accessible.  */
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="setUp()">
<div>

<div class="images">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/ff4400/fff.png&text=1" alt="1" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/3c00ff/fff.png&text=2" alt="2" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/44a10f/fff.png&text=3" alt="3" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/d99f2b/fff.png&text=4" alt="4" class="image">
</div>

<div id="content" class="content" onscroll="transOpacity()" style="height: 50vh; overflow:auto;">
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 1.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 2.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 3.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 4.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 5.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 6.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 7.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 8.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 9.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 10.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 11.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 12.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 13.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 14.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 15.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 16.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 17.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 18.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 19.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 20.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 21.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 22.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 23.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 24.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 25.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 26.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 27.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 28.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 29.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 30.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

***Version 2***

To change the smoothness adjust the constant opacityIncDec.  The smaller the value the smoother the transition but the longer it will take.

```js
var images;
var scrollContainer;
var noScrollDown;
var noScrollUp;
var scrollLeft;
var scrollTop;
var imgNdx;
const opacityIncDec = 0.025;
function setUp() {

    images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

    scrollContainer = document.getElementById("content");
    noScrollDown = true;
    noScrollUp = true;
    scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
    scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
    imgNdx = 1;
}

function doScrollUp () {
    noScrollUp = false;
    noScrollDown = true;
    imgNdx = 1;
}

function doScrollDown () {
    noScrollDown = false;
    noScrollUp = true;
    imgNdx = 3;
}

function fadeIn(ndx) {
    var opacity;
    if ( ndx > 3 ) {
        //  Top image is showing so switch direction of allowable scrolling
        doScrollDown();
    } else {
        //  Fade in an image or queue the fade in of the next image
        opacity = images[ndx].style.opacity;
        if ( opacity == "" ) {
            opacity = 0;
        } else {
            opacity = parseFloat(opacity);
        }
        if ( opacity < 1 ) {
            images[ndx].style.opacity = opacity + opacityIncDec
        } else {
            imgNdx += 1;
        }
    }
}

function fadeOut(ndx) {
    if ( ndx < 1 ) {
        //  Bottom image is showing so switch direction of allowable scrolling
        doScrollUp();
    } else {
        //  Fade out an image and queue the fade out of the next image
        opacity = images[ndx].style.opacity;
        if ( opacity == "" ) {
            opacity = 0;
        } else {
            opacity = parseFloat(opacity);
        }
        if ( opacity > 0 ) {
            images[ndx].style.opacity = opacity - opacityIncDec
        } else {
            imgNdx -= 1;
        }
    }
}

function transOpacity() {
    if ( noScrollDown && scrollContainer.scrollTop >= scrollTop ) {
        //  No scroll down allowed, and scroll event tried to go down
        
        //  Scroll back to where the scroll was
        scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);  //  This will trigger another scroll event
        fadeIn(imgNdx);
    } else if ( noScrollUp && scrollContainer.scrollTop <= scrollTop ) {
        //  No scroll up allowed, and scroll event tried to go up
        
        //  Scroll back to where the scroll was
        scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);  //  This will trigger another scroll event
        fadeOut(imgNdx)
    } else {
        scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
        scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
    }
}
```

```css
.images img {
    width: 100%;            /*  Note that 100% width will cover the scroll bar of the content, when the flow is decoupled with 'display: position;'  */
    max-height: 25vh;       /*  Set a limit on the height of the images, for this example, so that the scroll bar of the content can be fully accessible */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0vh;                 /*  Set the position, for this example, so that the scroll bar of the content can be fully accessible */
}


/*  Set up the required transition on the property relevant property  */

.images img.image {
    opacity: 0;                     /*  The default initial opacity  */
}

/*  Initialise the first image as showing, ie, full opacity.  */

.images img.image:nth-of-type(1) {
    opacity: 1;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 25vh;       /*  For this example, make sure the scroll container is below the images so that the scroll bar is fully accessible.  */
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="setUp()">
<div>

<div class="images">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/ff4400/fff.png&text=1" alt="1" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/3c00ff/fff.png&text=2" alt="2" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/44a10f/fff.png&text=3" alt="3" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/d99f2b/fff.png&text=4" alt="4" class="image">
</div>

<div id="content" class="content" onscroll="transOpacity()" style="height: 50vh; overflow:auto;">
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 1.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 2.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 3.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 4.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 5.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 6.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 7.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 8.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 9.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 10.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 11.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 12.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 13.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 14.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 15.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 16.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 17.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 18.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 19.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 20.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 21.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 22.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 23.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 24.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 25.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 26.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 27.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 28.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 29.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 30.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

***Version 3***

- When at top of scroll container images fade in over each other by
  means of their opacity increasing incrementally each time there is a
  scroll event.
- When at bottom of scroll container images fade out off each other by
  means of their opacity decreasing incrementally each time there is a
  scroll event.
- When the images have either fully faded in, the scroll having been at
  the top, or fully faded out, the scroll having been at the bottom,
  the contents of the scroll container all scroll normally and
  together, both the images and the text.
- Image opacity is not effected while normal scrolling occurs.

```js
var images;
var imgNdx;

var scrollContainer;
var atTop;
var atBottom;
var scrollLeft;
var scrollTop;

const opacityIncDec = 0.025;

function setUp() {

    images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    imgNdx = 1;

    scrollContainer = document.getElementById("scrollContainer");
    atTop = true;
    atBottom = false;
    scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
    scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
}

function fadeIn(ndx) {
    var opacity;
    if ( ndx > 3 ) {
        atTop = false;
        imgNdx = 3;
    } else {
        opacity = images[ndx].style.opacity;
        if ( opacity == "" ) {
            opacity = 0;
        } else {
            opacity = parseFloat(opacity);
        }
        if ( opacity < 1 ) {
            images[ndx].style.opacity = opacity + opacityIncDec
        } else {
            imgNdx += 1;
        }
    }
}

function fadeOut(ndx) {
    var opacity;
    if ( ndx < 1 ) {
        atBottom = false;
        imgNdx = 1;
    } else {
        opacity = images[ndx].style.opacity;
        if ( opacity == "" ) {
            opacity = 0;
        } else {
            opacity = parseFloat(opacity);
        }
        if ( opacity > 0 ) {
            images[ndx].style.opacity = opacity - opacityIncDec
        } else {
            imgNdx -= 1;
        }
    }
}

function transOpacity() {
    if ( atTop && scrollContainer.scrollTop >= scrollTop ) {
        //  At top, and scroll event tried to go down
        //  Scroll back to where the scroll was
        scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
        fadeIn(imgNdx);
    } else if ( atBottom && scrollContainer.scrollTop <= scrollTop ) {
        //  At bottom, and scroll event tried to go up
        //  Scroll back to where the scroll was
        scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);
        fadeOut(imgNdx)
    } else {
        atTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop <= 0;
        atBottom = Math.abs(scrollContainer.clientHeight - scrollContainer.scrollHeight + scrollContainer.scrollTop) <= 1;
        scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
        scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
    }
}
```

```css
.scrollContainer {
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.images {
    position: relative;
    height: 15vh;
}

.images img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
    position: absolute;
}

.images img.image {
    opacity: 0;                     /*  The default initial opacity  */
}

/*  Initialise the first image as showing, ie, full opacity.  */

.images img.image:nth-of-type(1) {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="setUp()">
<div id="scrollContainer" class="scrollContainer" onscroll="transOpacity()" >

<div class="images">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/ff4400/fff.png&text=1" alt="1" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/3c00ff/fff.png&text=2" alt="2" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/44a10f/fff.png&text=3" alt="3" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/d99f2b/fff.png&text=4" alt="4" class="image">
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 1.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 2.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 3.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 4.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 5.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 6.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 7.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 8.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 9.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 10.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 11.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 12.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 13.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 14.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 15.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 16.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 17.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 18.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 19.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 20.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 21.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 22.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 23.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 24.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 25.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 26.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 27.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 28.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 29.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 30.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

***Version 4***

Opacity processing now only occurs at the "top" of the scroll.  If the "image scroll" is only part way through it will go in the "direction of the scroll" within the images.

Note that in order to allow scroll events to keep firing, scrollTop must be kept above 0, otherwise there is no up scroll even fired.

As far as I can tell, is works correctly(?) except sometimes for very high scroll event rates when it gets overwhelmed and still gets a scrollTop of 0.  One single scroll down action though will reset things for the user. See the warning at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event.  This also offers some solutions.  This may be a problem on touch devices where a swipe scroll may swamp it.  But, this is going to depend on your context and getting into other areas altogether.

```js
var images;
var imgNdx;

var scrollContainer;
var atTop;
var scrollLeft;
var scrollTop;

const opacityIncDec = 0.05;

function setUp() {

    images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
    imgNdx = 1;

    scrollContainer = document.getElementById("scrollContainer");
    atTop = true;
    scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
    scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;
}

function fadeIn(ndx) {
    var opacity = images[ndx].style.opacity;
    if ( opacity == "" ) {
        opacity = 0;
    } else {
        opacity = parseFloat(opacity);
    }
    if ( opacity < 1 ) {
        images[ndx].style.opacity = opacity + opacityIncDec
    } else {
        imgNdx += 1;
        if ( imgNdx > 3 ) {
            imgNdx = 3;
            atTop = false;
        }
    }
}

function fadeOut(ndx) {
    var opacity = images[ndx].style.opacity;
    if ( opacity == "" ) {
        opacity = 0;
    } else {
        opacity = parseFloat(opacity);
    }
    if ( opacity > 0 ) {
        images[ndx].style.opacity = opacity - opacityIncDec
    } else {
        imgNdx -= 1;
        if ( ndx < 1 ) {
            imgNdx = 1;
        }
    }
}

var latch = false;
function transOpacity() {
    if ( atTop ) {
        if ( ! latch ) {
            if ( scrollContainer.scrollTop > 1 ) {
                //  Scroll event tried to go down
                //  Scroll back to the "top"
                latch = true;
                scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, 1);
                fadeIn(imgNdx);
            } else {
                //  Scroll event tried to go up
                //  Scroll back to the "top"
                latch = true;
                scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, 1);
                if ( imgNdx > 0 ) fadeOut(imgNdx);
            }
        } else {
            latch = false;
        }
    } else {
        scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
        if ( scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0 ) {
            atTop = true;
            latch = true;
            scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollLeft, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.scrollContainer {
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.images {
    position: relative;
    height: 15vh;
}

.images img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
    position: absolute;
}

.images img.image {
    opacity: 0;                     /*  The default initial opacity  */
}

/*  Initialise the first image as showing, ie, full opacity.  */

.images img.image:nth-of-type(1) {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="setUp()">
<div id="scrollContainer" class="scrollContainer" onscroll="transOpacity()" >

<div class="images">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/ff4400/fff.png&text=1" alt="1" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/3c00ff/fff.png&text=2" alt="2" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/44a10f/fff.png&text=3" alt="3" class="image">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/d99f2b/fff.png&text=4" alt="4" class="image">
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 1.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 2.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 3.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 4.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 5.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 6.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 7.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 8.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 9.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 10.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 11.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 12.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 13.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 14.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 15.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 16.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 17.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 18.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 19.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 20.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 21.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 22.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 23.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 24.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 25.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 26.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 27.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 28.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 29.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally - line 30.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't follow the requirements. The opacity changing behavior only needs to change while the user is scrolling down (to increase opacity) and while the user scrolls up (to decrease opacity). There should be no automatic opacity change into the next image at all.

Comment: Sorry, but then it is not clear what you require. Above you say 'by smoothly changing the opacity from 0 to 1', but here you say 'no automatic capacity change'. Note that fading in an element stacked over the top of another element will like the underneath element is fading out, even if it is not. Did you want the underneath element to be not visible at all as soon as the new image starts to fade in? This can be easily done. If not can you please clarify what you need.

Comment: I think I have worked out that you meant that 'the attempted scrolling action itself is to control the opacity transition'.  Accordingly, please find above a second version of the solution.  If this is not the case, then I think your question needs to be much clearer in what it is asking.  You may wish to review what you want to happen if the user changes direction before they get to the top or bottom of a scroll, and then changes direction again.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for the questions -- I added a bounty for this answer, happy to award it to you but there are still two issues that would need to be solved. 1) once the image reaches the 4th image, then everything needs to start scrolling normally (including the images). 2) The scroll Up behavior for the images should only restart working once we are back on the top of the page, just as the scroll Down behavior should only start working if you're on the top of the page. Right now, despite on the scroll position on the page, the opacity changes.

Comment: 1 and 2, can do I am almost certain, but cannot write up the new solution for about 12 hours.  I have some other commitments in the meantime.

Comment: I think I have got your requirements working.  You may wish to review what happens when scrolling down and the images scroll out of view.  They will still fade out, but that activity will not be visible.

Comment: Thanks again, the only problem I'm experiencing (and can't get rid of) is that when trying to scroll up (while on the bottom of the page) it blocks the scroll until the image Number 1 is displayed. It should let me scroll all the way up, and only if I'm on top, the image opacity should start reversing. That also applies if I'm on image 1, scroll down, image 2 is displayed, and scroll back up, so image 1 should be displayed once again.

Comment: No problem. I can fix that too, but I am committed elsewhere at the moment and it might be a day or two before I can do it.

Comment: Version 4 now done.  You a need to consider high scroll event rates, but that is getting in to a whole other area. See above addition to answer for further comments.

Answer (score 0):

try using `whell` event

```js
let images = $(".images img");
var imagesTotal = images.length;
var currentIndex = 0;
var isScrolling = false;
var isScrollFinish = false;

$(window).on("wheel", function (e) {
  if(isScrollFinish) return;
  let event = e.originalEvent;
  clearTimeout(isScrolling);
  isScrolling = setTimeout(function () {
    if (event.deltaY < 0 && currentIndex > 0) {
      images.eq(currentIndex).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 600);
      currentIndex--;
      images.eq(currentIndex).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
      console.log("scrolling up", currentIndex+1);
    } else if (event.deltaY > 0 && currentIndex < imagesTotal) {
      images.eq(currentIndex).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 600);
      currentIndex++;
      images.eq(currentIndex).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
      if (currentIndex == imagesTotal) {
        isScrollFinish = true;
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
      }
      console.log("scrolling down", currentIndex+1);
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0
}

.images img.img1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.as-console-wrapper{max-height:24px !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/ff4400/fff.png&text=1" alt="1" class="img1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/3c00ff/fff.png&text=2" alt="2" class="img2">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/44a10f/fff.png&text=3" alt="3" class="img3">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/d99f2b/fff.png&text=4" alt="4" class="img4">
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
  <p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is "exactly" in lines with your question, but maybe it will help...

I made something similar using bootstrap 4's native scroll-spy behavior. It reads the scroll position of an element (id) and uses an anchor (#) to point to that matching element. You could use images inside the anchor tags and pretty much accomplish the same thing.

Source:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/

Too much code to place here, so I made a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ytdpmL9e/1/

SO makes me add some code anyway, so here is just the CSS...

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
html {scroll-padding-top: 140px;}
body {position:relative;}
#main {background:#f6f6f6; padding:3em 2em; margin-top:-2.5em; max-width:600px;}
#header {opacity:0;}
#header.show {background:#fff; display:flex; flex-direction:column; position:sticky; top:0px; text-align:center; min-height:125px; opacity:1; transition:all 0.3s;}
#header.show .nav {height:125px;}
#header.show .nav a {color:#fff; display:flex; font-size:1.8em; align-items:center; justify-content:center; min-height:125px; max-width:600px; width:100%;}
#header.show .nav a:nth-child(1) {background:#6b78b9;}
#header.show .nav a:nth-child(2) {background:#8db33f;}
#header.show .nav a:nth-child(3) {background:#f68e1e;}
#header.show .nav a.active {animation:fade-in .5s; position:absolute; top:0; z-index:100;}
#header.show .nav a:not(.active) {animation:fade-out .5s; opacity:0; position:absolute; transition-delay:.1s;}
@keyframes fade-in {0% {opacity: 0;} 100% {opacity: 1;}}
@keyframes fade-out {0% {opacity: 1;} 100% {opacity: 0;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, paste this into your jsfiddle in the JS section:

```
var scrollDirection = 0;
var scrollTimeout = null;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > scrollDirection) {
        // scroll down
        if (scrollTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
        }
        scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.images img').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.css('opacity') == 0) {
                    $this.css('opacity', 1);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    } else {
        // scroll up
        if (scrollTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
        }
        scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.images img').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.css('opacity') == 1) {
                    $this.css('opacity', 0);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }, 500);
    }
    scrollDirection = scrollTop;
});
```

You will probably need to enable jQuery from the gear icon, or, you can try pasting this at the top of the code:

```
import $ from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery@3.6.1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, in this very case using [deltaY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY) of [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent) event for vertical scroll amount calculation. For more advanced scenarios, other events, such as `touchmove`, could be handled in a similar way:

```js
const scroll = (() => {
  let v = 0, i = 0;
  const images = document.querySelector('.images');
  const top = images.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  const img = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  const cls = document.body.classList;
  const len = img.length, max = len - 1;

  return (dy, step = 1) => {
    if (images.getBoundingClientRect().top - top)
      return;
    v = Math.min(Math.max(v += Math.sign(dy) * step, 0), len * 100);
    (i = (v - v % 100) / 100) === 0 && (v = 100);
    let o = v - i * 100;
    i > max ? (i = max, o = 100, cls.remove('fixed')) : cls.add('fixed');
    for (let n = img.length; n--;)
      img[n].style.opacity = `${n === i ? o : n < i ? 100 : 0}%`;
  };
})();

scroll(0);
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => scroll(e.deltaY, 10), true);
```

```css
.images img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.images img:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
body.fixed {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/ff4400/fff.png&text=1" alt="1" class="img1">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/3c00ff/fff.png&text=2" alt="2" class="img2">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/44a10f/fff.png&text=3" alt="3" class="img3">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1400x600/d99f2b/fff.png&text=4" alt="4" class="img4">
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
<p>This should be scrolled down normally.</p>
</div>
```